# Is -fsanitize=bounds-strict included in -fsanitize=undefined for GCC 6?

Tags: c++, sanitizer, ubsan, gcc6

I'm working on a problem report for a C++ library compiled with GCC 6. I'm reading through the [GCC 6 Changes, New Features, and Fixes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html), and one of the notes is:

- UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer gained a new sanitization option, -fsanitize=bounds-strict, which enables strict checking of array bounds. In particular, it enables -fsanitize=bounds as well as instrumentation of flexible array member-like arrays.

Is strict bounds checking included in `-fsanitize=undefined`? Or do we need both `-fsanitize=undefined` and `-fsanitize=bounds-strict`?

Comment: You need both: `-fsanitize=address,undefined,bounds-strict`

Comment: @Jeroen - Thanks. You should provide an answer.